# Is there a good way to go from running Docker Containers to Kubernetes Deployments?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I am working in a sort of remote/external environment that I don't know too much about, and have been working with containers locally in docker.

I am trying to transition this environment to Kubernetes deployments.

My current containers look like

- nginx
- php-fpm
- mariadb

I found [rekcod](https://github.com/nexdrew/rekcod), as a way to do Docker inspect pipe that to a json file, however I am trying to find an easy way to transition that into a Kubernetes deployment with the understanding that deployments are frequently defined separately, with yamls and different configuration.

These containers **were deployed with arguments or a file that I don't know much about**, that is why I'm trying to use the current inspect information given to me.

Maybe the *best* answer is create a Kubernetes deployment yaml that somehow ingests those json sort of *docker run* commands and creates it that way?

Any direction or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'd strongly suggest writing correct Kubernetes YAML and committing it to source control.  That involves both understanding the Kubernetes pod/service model and knowing the settings you need to launch the container.

Comment: Piggy-backing on @DavidMaze's comment I'd suggest playing around with the [`helm`](https://helm.sh/) package manager and create charts for your application / familiarize yourself with using the already [existing charts](https://github.com/helm/charts) that you can leverage to deploy your application i.e. [`stable/mariadb`](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mariadb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion from docker to kubernetes should go like this:

- try start your project locally using docker-compose https://docs.docker.com/compose/
- try to convert your docker-compose project to Kubernetes with "kompose" - https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose
- explore created kubernetes files created with step above and learn deployments, pods and services.
- learn helm (https://helm.sh/) as tool for managing deployments (helm - templates for kubernetes files)